# Manipulating WebVTT cues through jquery

Tags: jquery, video, caption, subtitle, webvtt

I would like to manipulate the pseudo element: **"::cue"** through jquery. Let's say that I have a video like this:

```
<video id="my_video">
  <source src="my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <track src="my_subtitles.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English">
</video>
```

How can I dynamically change the color of its subtitles with jquery?

I tried this:

```
$('#my_video::cue').css({
  'color': '#ff0000 !important'
});
```

But it is not working. The only thing I got working was:

```
$('#captions_style').remove();
$('head').append(
  '<style id="captions_style">#my_video::cue{color: #ff0000 !important}</style>'
);
```

But I find this not elegant. Is there any other way?

Thanks & best regards
Josef

Answer (score 0):

Just like an element that must be added to your class `::before` or `::after` the element `::cue` applies the same rule, it cannot be changed directly by `javascript` or `jquery`, for example, but is possible to add class and remove classes from an element, so you can make a bit more dynamic code like this:

Your HTML file

```
<video id="my_video_element" controls loop>

    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track kind="captions" src="web.vtt" srclang=" EN " label="EN">

</video>

<!-- this button/link this button will change the values -->
<a href="#" class="chance_caption">Click to change VTT</a>
```

Your CSS file
    .alphaclass::cue{

```
    background: #09f;
    color: #000;

}
```

And the JS with Jquery file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.chance_caption').click(function(){

        $('#my_video_element').addClass('alphaclass');

        return false;

    });

});
```

The advantage of making for classes that when you define in one video element you can apply in another using `utilizando $(element).removeClass(‘NameClass’);` and `$(element).addClass(‘NameClass’);`.

I hope I was helpfull.